# Sign in Java and verify in Go Lang

Tags: java, go, rsa, sign, verify

I have a logic to sign data in Java as below:

```
public String encryptWithRSA(String data) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException, SignatureException {
        Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        privateSignature.initSign(getPrivateKey());
        privateSignature.update(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
    }
```

I need to verify the signature in Go Lang. I have the code as below:

```
func validData(tcktsignature string, ticketInfo string) bool {

    message := []byte(ticketInfo)
    hashed := sha256.Sum256(message)
    log.Printf("Hash value = %x",hashed)

    signature, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(tcktsignature)
    err := rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15(getPublicKey(), crypto.SHA256, hashed[:], signature)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error from verification: %s\n", err)
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func getPublicKey() (PublicKey *rsa.PublicKey) {

    pubPEM := getFileContent(pubKeyPath)
    key, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(pubPEM)
    re, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    pub := re.(*rsa.PublicKey)
    return pub
}
```

But Go Lang gives me the error : **Error from verification: crypto/rsa: verification error**

I compared the Has value generated in both Java and Go Lang are same. But I am not sure on why it is failing. Can someone help me out?

The private key in Java is generated in the following fashion:

```
KeyPair generateRSAKeys() {
        KeyPair keyPair = null;
        try {
            File privateKeyFile = new File(PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME);
            File publicKeyFile = new File(PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME);

            if (!privateKeyFile.exists() || !publicKeyFile.exists()) {
                KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                kpg.initialize(2048);
                keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
                writeToFile(PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME, keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
                writeToFile(PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME, keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return keyPair;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have copy of verification logic on Java? If no - try to implement and check, will help to investigate if error is in signature itself or that's something wrong with Go implementation.

Comment: @AlexChernyshev, below is the verification logic in Java:

`public static boolean verify(String plainText, String signature, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
  Signature publicSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
  publicSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
  publicSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(UTF_8));

  byte[] signatureBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);

  return publicSignature.verify(signatureBytes);
 }`

Comment: i don't see any utf-8 decoding steps in golang part - missed?

Comment: UTF-8 decoding? I have done the base64 decoding `base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString`

Comment: I would add in Java and Go code to print the `byte[]` data to be signed/to be verified in base64 or hex encoding just to make sure the messages are really equal. Another option is to apply RSA decrypt on the signature (using the RSA public key). Then you will get the message hash so that you can compare the hash generated by Java with those generated by Go.